# Encrypt String to half it size and be able to decrypt again in flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart, encryption

I am trying to achieve this: In dart, take a string of an ObjectId (MongoDB) make it half it size for external urls and then decoded in the app when the link is used.

I want this to avoid to make the ids of my items public, but not idea how to make it so far, do you have any?

Comment: By the rules of information theory, that is not possible in general.  For any algorithm that can compress to half the size for *common* URLs, it will necessarily also produce encodings that *maintain* or *increase* the size for *uncommon* URLs.  There's no way around that.

Comment: Rather than "encrypting" a string you just need to map a string (url) to another shorter string (id). It can be as simple as using the sequential numeric id of the link as it is added to the database, most map it to characters though (eg base36 representation of the id)